# angular 4: how to connect 2 or 3 services handling HTTP API calls so my services wont be crowded

Tags: angular-services

I have multiple http calls in my api.service as my core service in all my component.I'm currently using CRUD with different models. I'm currently in my 2nd Crud Http call in my api.service and its becoming crowded  and I think its a bad idea if I put all my calls in only one services. 
I have my api-services.ts

```
e
```

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

// declaration of models
import {SubjectModel} from '../model/subject';
import {CurriculumModel} from '../model/curriculum';
import {SectionModel} from '../model/section';
import {StudentModel} from '../model/student';
import {TeacherModel} from '../model/teacher';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class ApiService {
  private subjects: SubjectModel[] = [];

  api = 'http://localhost:3000/api';

  constructor( private httpClient: HttpClient) { }


  /**********
   * SUBJECT API
   *
   * ***************/

  // Get list of public, future Subject
  getSubjectList$(): Observable<SubjectModel[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<SubjectModel[]>(`${this.api}/subjects/admin`);
  }
  // add new SUBJECT
  addSubject$(subject: SubjectModel): Observable<SubjectModel> {
    return this.httpClient.post<SubjectModel>(`${this.api} /subjects/new`, subject);
  }
  // Get subject by ID query, get for singletodo
  getSubjectById$(id: string): Observable<SubjectModel> {
    return this.httpClient.get<SubjectModel>(`${this.api}/subjects/admin/${id}`);
  }
  // subject put or editing subject
  editSubject$(id: number, subject: SubjectModel): Observable<SubjectModel> {
    return this.httpClient.put<SubjectModel>(`${this.api}/subjects/${id}`, subject );
  }
  // delete subject (admin Only)
  deleteSubject$(id: number): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.delete(`${this.api}/subjects/${id}`);
  }


  /**********
   * CURRICULUM API
   *
   * ***************/

  // add new CURRICULUM
  addCurriculum$(subject: CurriculumModel): Observable<CurriculumModel> {
    return this.httpClient.post<CurriculumModel>(`${this.api}/curriculum/new`, subject);
  }
  // Get list of public, future Subject
  getCurriculumList$(): Observable<CurriculumModel[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<CurriculumModel[]>(`${this.api}/curriculum/admin`);
  }
  // Get subject by ID query, get for singletodo
  getCurriculumById$(id: string): Observable<CurriculumModel> {
    return this.httpClient.get<CurriculumModel>(`${this.api}/curriculum/admin/${id}`);
  }
  // subject put
  editCurriculum$(id: number, curriculum: CurriculumModel): Observable<CurriculumModel> {
    return this.httpClient.put<CurriculumModel>(`${this.api}/curriculum/${id}`, curriculum );
  }
  // delete subject (admin Only)
  deleteCurriculum$(id: number): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.delete(`${this.api}/curriculum/${id}`);
  }



    /**********
     * SECTION API
     *
     * ***************/

  // add new SECTION
  addSection$(section: SectionModel): Observable<SectionModel> {
    return this.httpClient.post<SectionModel>(`${this.api} /posts`, section);
  }



    /**********
     * STUDENT API
     *
     * ***************/
  // add new STUDENT
  addStudent$(student: StudentModel): Observable<StudentModel> {
    return this.httpClient.post<StudentModel>(`${this.api} /posts`, student);
  }



    /**********
     * TEACHER API
     *
     * ***************/
  // add new TEACHER
  addTeacher$(teacher: TeacherModel): Observable<TeacherModel> {
    return this.httpClient.post<TeacherModel>(`${this.api} /posts`, teacher);
  }


}
```

I will create new api serves.ts, will I inject it to my services or directly to my component?

if injected to my services, how can I implement such thing.?

solutions or opinions will much be appreciated.
thanks!

Comment: If there is no inherent problem with your code you may wanna take it over to code review stack exchange.

Comment: so far so good, thanks i'll try it.